# How to share URL link of app in react-native using Share()?

Tags: react-native, share, deep-linking, react-native-navigation

I like to share the app link through social media so that when the receiver click the shared link it will open the App installed with the information shared(deep linking).
**Please find the code here :**

```
onShare = (articleShare) => {
    try {
        const result = Share.share({
                title: articleShare.articleTitle,
                message: articleShare.articleContent,
                url:'AppName://ArticleDetail/'+articleShare._id,
            },
            {dialogTitle: 'Share Article',});
        if (result.action === Share.sharedAction) {
            Meteor.call('ShareArticleNotification', articleShare);
        };
    } catch (error) {
        alert(error.message);
    };
};
```

Comment: did you resolve this?

Comment: The `url` parameter currently works only on iOS, not on Android. You can try `react-native-share` instead...

Answer (score 0):

```js
 const result = await Share.share({
        message: `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana&hl=en&gl=US`,
      });
```